# Trocar parte de String em todas as colunas do dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Possuo um dataframe no seguinte modelo:

```
lista = []
lista.append(['A1','2','A3'])
lista.append(['4','A5','6'])
lista.append(['A7','8','9'])

df = pd.DataFrame(lista, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

**df:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Oque desejo é retirar o carácter **'A'** de todas as colunas. Sei que consigo tirar isso indo coluna por coluna com o comando *(df.Series)*:

```
df.A.replace('A', '', regex = True)
df.B.replace('A', '', regex = True)
df.C.replace('A', '', regex = True)
```

*Resultado:*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, gostaria de montar uma função que percorresse todo meu dataframe removendo esse carácter especifico.

Tentei realizar uma iteração sobre as colunas e pegar cada uma da seguinte maneira:

```
for column in df.columns[1:]:
    print(column)
    df[column] = df.column.replace('A', '', regex = True)
```

Porém me retorna o seguinte erro:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'column'

Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode usar a função pré-definida [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html), da seguinte forma:

```
df.replace({'A': ''}, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Dado o seu dataframe, o resultado será:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
```

Comment: Não sabia da possibilidade de não utilizar o comando _replace_ diretamente. Funcionou muito bem, muito obrigado bruno!